# Connect clicked button value and function in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, click

I'm beginner in JS.

I have 2 functions. How to do :

1. if I click first button, make first function work, if I click second button, make second function work?
2. Apply pressed button value to function and then apply it to input field.

Example: when I type 'ABC' using Caesar Cipher , it would return 'NOP', when I type 'ABC' using my cipher (or any other), it would return 'BCD' (or any other value, it depends on which cipher is selected). Thanks everyone in advance

My Js and Html code below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form  class="col s12 m12 l12">
    <h2>JS Encription</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
          <input id="field1" placeholder="Type you text here" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name">Input</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
          <input id="field2" disabled placeholder="Result is shown here" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name">Output</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
      <div class="row switchBtns">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
            <div id="caesarButton" class="col s3 m3 l3 ">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">Caesar Cipher</a>
            </div>
            <div id="mineButton" class="col s3 m3 l3 ">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">My Cipher</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col s3 m3 l3 ">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">3rd Variant</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col s3 m3 l3 ">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">4th Variant</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS code

```
 // CAESAR
        $("#caesarButton").click(function() {
            var clicked = $(this).val();
            $('#field1').val(encryp(clicked)).val();
        });

        $('#field1').on('keyup keypress blur', function () {  
            var textvalue = $(this).val();
            $('#field2').val(encryp(textvalue)).val();  
        });


        function encryp(tekst) {
            var result = "";
            var str = tekst.toUpperCase();


            for (var i=0; i<str.length ; i++) {
                var ascii = str[i].charCodeAt();

                if(ascii>=65 && ascii<=77) {
                    result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii+13);
                }
                else if(ascii>=78 && ascii<=90) {
                    result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii-13);
                }
                else {
                    result+=" ";
                }
            }
            return result ;
        }

        //MINE
        $("#mineButton").click(function() {
            var clicked = $(this).val();
            $('#field1').val(encryp(clicked)).val();
        });

        $('#field1').on('keyup keypress blur', function () {  
            var textvalue = $(this).val();
            $('#field2').val(encryp(textvalue)).val();  
        });


        function encryp(tekst) {
            var result = "";
            var str = tekst.toUpperCase();


            for (var i=0; i<str.length ; i++) {
                var ascii = str[i].charCodeAt();

                if(ascii>=65 && ascii<=77) {
                    result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii+3);
                }
                else if(ascii>=78 && ascii<=90) {
                    result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii-3);
                }
                else {
                    result+=" ";
                }
            }
            return result ;
        }
```

Comment: You have two functions with the same name. This means that the function defined later overrides the former one. Try naming your functions by what they do, eg. encryptCaesarCipher() and encryptMyCipher() or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whipped up a simplified example of contextually switching input handler functions for you, here ya go:

```js
// use an object as a key-value store for your functions
var funcs = {
  caesar: encryp1, // i dont know if i got these the right way around :D
  mine: encryp2
}
// store which funciton is currently selected in a variable
var selected = "caesar"

// call this function just to show the default selected function
determineOutput()

// CAESAR
$("#caesarButton").click(function() {
  console.log("caesar button clicked!")
  // here assign which function to use
  selected = "caesar"
  determineOutput()
});

//MINE
$("#mineButton").click(function() {
  console.log("mine button clicked!")
  // here assign which function to use
  selected = "mine"
  determineOutput()
});

$('#field1').on('keyup keypress blur', function () {  
  // this function is alled every time one of the events 
  // listed happens on the #field1 element
  determineOutput()
});

function determineOutput(){
  var textvalue = $('#field1').val();
  //use the function currently selected by addressing it with 
  // [] on the funcs object
  var correctFunction = funcs[selected]
  // then call the selected function with the input text
  $('#field2').val(correctFunction(textvalue));  
  // show the user which cipher we're using
  $("#currentCipher").html("current cipher:" + selected)
}


function encryp1(tekst) {
  var result = "";
  var str = tekst.toUpperCase();


  for (var i=0; i<str.length ; i++) {
    var ascii = str[i].charCodeAt();

    if(ascii>=65 && ascii<=77) {
      result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii+13);
    }
    else if(ascii>=78 && ascii<=90) {
      result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii-13);
    }
    else {
      result+=" ";
    }
  }
  return result ;
}

function encryp2(tekst) {
  var result = "";
  var str = tekst.toUpperCase();


  for (var i=0; i<str.length ; i++) {
    var ascii = str[i].charCodeAt();

    if(ascii>=65 && ascii<=77) {
      result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii+3);
    }
    else if(ascii>=78 && ascii<=90) {
      result+=String.fromCharCode(ascii-3);
    }
    else {
      result+=" ";
    }
  }
  return result ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="field1" placeholder="Type you text here" type="text">
  <label for="field1">Input</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input id="field2" disabled placeholder="Result is shown here" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="field2">Output</label>
</div>

<p id="currentCipher"></p>

<button id="caesarButton">
  Caesar Cipher
</button>

<button id="mineButton">
  My Cipher
</button>
```